# Add custom post type to Backbone collections

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api, backbone

I am trying to fetch posts of a custom post type (cpt) with the [backbone js client](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/).

I registered the cpt with the show_in_rest param set to true.
I enqueued the wp-api script.

The url http://myweb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/custom works.

In the js, this works:

```
wp.api.loadPromise.done( function() {

       var _posts = new wp.api.collections.Posts();

});
```

but this does not:

```
wp.api.loadPromise.done( function() {

       var _custom = new wp.api.collections.Custom();

} );
```

saying "wp.api.collections.Custom is not a constructor"

Why?

ps: I registered to cpt like this:

```
register_post_type('custom', array(
    'label' => 'Custom',
    'public' => true,        
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    ...
));
```

Comment: you can try to add  `'rest_base' => 'custom',` and  `'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller'`

Comment: yes thanks, i already tried that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/#working-with-revisions): (scroll down to the "Working With Revisions" section on that page)

> Note: Because the schema is stored in the user’s session cache to
>   avoid re-fetching, you may need to open a new tab to get a new read of
>   the Schema.

**So it's probably just a caching issue and you only needed to open a new (browser) tab**, or test your code in another tab or window.

However, if you don't want to having to open another tab/window, then you can force the browser to delete the session cache for the schema ***right after*** WordPress defined the `wpApiSettings` variable which is when the `wp-api-request` script (`wp-includes/js/api-request.js`) is enqueued.

So for that purpose, you can use [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/):

```php
// Enqueue the Backbone client library.
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api' ); // this includes the wp-api-request (api-request.js) script

// And then delete the session cache. Note: Don't include the <script> and </script> tags!
wp_add_inline_script( 'wp-api-request', "try { sessionStorage.removeItem( 'wp-api-schema-model' + wpApiSettings.root + wpApiSettings.versionString ); } catch ( err ) {}" );
```

But then, I'm not recommending the above — the schema is already quite a lot by default and it could take some time for the browser to request the schema and then process it via the Backbone client. But I shared the code as an option if you absolutely must reset the cache *every time* the page is loaded. Secondly, you can use the above code to confirm that you had a caching issue.

And by the way, apart from the Backbone client, you can actually use `wp.apiRequest()` to make request to the REST API endpoints:

- PHP: `wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api-request' );`
- JavaScript examples for a post type having `custom` as the slug:

  ```js
  // Fetch a collection (i.e. a list of posts).
  wp.apiRequest( { path: 'wp/v2/custom' } )
    .then( posts => console.log( posts ) );

  // Create a model/post.
  wp.apiRequest( {
    path: 'wp/v2/custom',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      title: 'New Custom Post',
      content: 'Just testing',
      // ..other data, if any..
    }
  } ).then( post => console.log( post ) );

  // Update a model/post.
  wp.apiRequest( {
    path: 'wp/v2/custom/123', // change 123 to the correct ID
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      title: 'New Title',
      // ..other data you want to UPDATE
    }
  } ).then( post => console.log( post ) );

  // Destroy a model/post.
  wp.apiRequest( {
    path: 'wp/v2/custom/123', // change 123 to the correct ID
    method: 'DELETE'
  } ).then( post => console.log( post.status ) ); // 'trash'
  ```

Comment: Correct! It was a caché issue. (I did not scroll down to 'working with revisions' in the docs because i was not working with revisions). Thank you! And thanks for the additional info : )

Comment: You're welcome! And about that revisions thing, I was just highlighting the quote (or specifically, that *need to open a new tab* part) which also applies to any endpoints (revisions, custom post types, etc.). :)